# How to add new customer group programmatically, in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm creating a module, which needs a new customer group, and I want to do it programmatically.

I looked at `controllers/admin/AdminGroupsController.php` there is nothing useful there, and there is a method by name of `addGroups` in `classes/Customer.php` and this one is not able to do what I want.

So, I would be thankful if someone help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use normal object creation of the `Group` class.
Something like this:

```
$group = new Group();
$group->name = array(Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT') => '[whatever]');
$group->price_display_method = [0 or 1];
$group->add();
```

should work. You can look at the Group class to see what the other properties are called and what their type is.